# Only return rows within two timestamp bounds - SQL - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have time series data for the stock exchange which is only open between 9am and 4pm. I wish to disregard any rows that fall outside these bounds.

To know if I need to make API calls I am comparing a generate_series for a given time period with the time series data I have stored in my db.

I am doing a LEFT JOIN against the generate_series results and my av_intraday tables.

This is the query...

```
SELECT *
FROM generate_series(date_trunc('day', localtimestamp - interval '1 day')
                    , localtimestamp
                    , interval '15 min') g(start_time)
LEFT JOIN av_intraday av ON av.date = g.start_time
                    AND extract(hour from g.start_time) >= 9 
                    AND extract(hour from g.start_time) <= 16
ORDER BY g.start_time;
```

This is the resulting data...

```
av_intraday

     start_time      | symbol |        date         |   open    |   high    |    low    |   close   | volume  
---------------------+--------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------

...
 2019-07-30 08:45:00 |        |                     |           |           |           |           |        
 2019-07-30 09:00:00 |        |                     |           |           |           |           |        
 2019-07-30 09:15:00 |        |                     |           |           |           |           |        
 2019-07-30 09:30:00 |        |                     |           |           |           |           |        
 2019-07-30 09:45:00 | fb     | 2019-07-30 09:45:00 |    194.95 |    195.83 |    194.54 |    195.58 | 2004674
 2019-07-30 09:45:00 | amzn   | 2019-07-30 09:45:00 |  1891.115 |    1905.3 |   1883.48 |   1904.28 |  564821
 2019-07-30 09:45:00 | goog   | 2019-07-30 09:45:00 |   1225.41 |   1234.87 | 1223.4301 | 1232.0699 |  203333
 2019-07-30 09:45:00 | tsla   | 2019-07-30 09:45:00 |       234 |    235.54 |    233.72 |    235.07 |  207546
 2019-07-30 09:45:00 | aapl   | 2019-07-30 09:45:00 |    208.88 |    208.93 |   208.335 |  208.6148 |  602413
...
 2019-07-30 16:00:00 | amzn   | 2019-07-30 16:00:00 |   1897.42 |    1899.9 |   1896.61 |   1898.33 |  152442
 2019-07-30 16:00:00 | goog   | 2019-07-30 16:00:00 |   1225.09 |   1226.34 |    1223.3 |    1223.4 |  169110
 2019-07-30 16:00:00 | tsla   | 2019-07-30 16:00:00 |    241.94 |     242.3 |    241.93 |     242.2 |  151572
 2019-07-30 16:00:00 | aapl   | 2019-07-30 16:00:00 |    208.94 |    208.94 |  208.3436 |   208.685 | 1096338
 2019-07-30 16:15:00 |        |                     |           |           |           |           |        
 2019-07-30 16:30:00 |        |                     |           |           |           |           |        
 2019-07-30 16:45:00 |        |                     |           |           |           |           |        
 2019-07-30 17:00:00 |        |                     |           |           |           |           |        
 2019-07-30 17:15:00 |        |                     |           |           |           |           |        
 2019-07-30 17:30:00 |        |                     |           |           |           |           |        
...
```

Data should look like the following...

```
av_intraday

     start_time      | symbol |        date         |   open    |   high    |    low    |   close   | volume  
---------------------+--------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------

 2019-07-30 09:00:00 |        |                     |           |           |           |           |        
 2019-07-30 09:15:00 |        |                     |           |           |           |           |        
 2019-07-30 09:30:00 |        |                     |           |           |           |           |        
 2019-07-30 09:45:00 | fb     | 2019-07-30 09:45:00 |    194.95 |    195.83 |    194.54 |    195.58 | 2004674
 2019-07-30 09:45:00 | amzn   | 2019-07-30 09:45:00 |  1891.115 |    1905.3 |   1883.48 |   1904.28 |  564821
 2019-07-30 09:45:00 | goog   | 2019-07-30 09:45:00 |   1225.41 |   1234.87 | 1223.4301 | 1232.0699 |  203333
 2019-07-30 09:45:00 | tsla   | 2019-07-30 09:45:00 |       234 |    235.54 |    233.72 |    235.07 |  207546
 2019-07-30 09:45:00 | aapl   | 2019-07-30 09:45:00 |    208.88 |    208.93 |   208.335 |  208.6148 |  602413
...
 2019-07-30 16:00:00 | amzn   | 2019-07-30 16:00:00 |   1897.42 |    1899.9 |   1896.61 |   1898.33 |  152442
 2019-07-30 16:00:00 | goog   | 2019-07-30 16:00:00 |   1225.09 |   1226.34 |    1223.3 |    1223.4 |  169110
 2019-07-30 16:00:00 | tsla   | 2019-07-30 16:00:00 |    241.94 |     242.3 |    241.93 |     242.2 |  151572
 2019-07-30 16:00:00 | aapl   | 2019-07-30 16:00:00 |    208.94 |    208.94 |  208.3436 |   208.685 | 1096338
 2019-07-30 16:15:00 |        |                     |           |           |           |           |        
 2019-07-30 16:30:00 |        |                     |           |           |           |           |        
 2019-07-30 16:45:00 |        |                     |           |           |           |           |        
...
```

Got the desired result with the following...

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT g.start_time as g_start_time, av.symbol, av.open, av.high, av.low, av.close, av.volume
    FROM generate_series(date_trunc('day', localtimestamp - interval '1 day')
                        , localtimestamp
                        , interval '15 min') g(start_time)
    LEFT JOIN av_intraday av ON av.date = g.start_time
    ORDER BY g.start_time
) t
WHERE extract(hour from g_start_time) >= 9
AND extract(hour from g_start_time) <= 16;
```

But I'm not sure why it wouldn't work as it was. Can someone explain? Thank you.

Comment: Could you fill in what the columns are in your result please? Particularly which table they're from.

Comment: @Schwern I've added the column names and table names for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LEFT JOIN av_intraday av ON av.date = g.start_time
                    AND extract(hour from g.start_time) >= 9 
                    AND extract(hour from g.start_time) <= 16
```

This says to match each row of the series against rows of `av_intraday` where the `date` matches the `start_time` and where the `start_time`'s hour is between 9 and 16 which effectively limits the `date` to those hours.

But this only effects the join. A `left join` will return all the rows of the left table; that is the `from` table, your series. Any row on the left without a match on the right will simply use null for the right columns. See the quite excellent [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/33052/%2fArticles%2f33052%2fVisual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) for more.

Instead you need to move your restrictions on the series into a `where` clause. There it will affect the entire query.

You also don't want to subtract a day from the localtime to start the series else it will start from the day before.

```
select *
from generate_series(
  date_trunc('day', localtimestamp),
  localtimestamp,
  interval '15 min'
) g(start_time)
left join av_intraday av
  on av.date = g.start_time
where extract(hour from g.start_time) between 9 and 16
order by g.start_time;
```